# Angular Asynchronous Validator Not Making Calls to Backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a directive that will asynchronously call my backend to see if a given customer is in the database yet, and report if that form field is then valid.

```
function getCustomerValidationDirectiveFunc(){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        var serverAddr = '/validate/customer/'

        ngModel.$validators.invalidUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            // validation logic here
            var username = modelValue || viewValue;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // ask the server if this username exists
            $http.get(serverAddr+username).then(
              function(response) {
                  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM SERVER")
                if (response.data.exists) {
                  deferred.reject();
                } else {
                  deferred.resolve();
                }
              });

            // return the promise of the asynchronous validator
            return deferred.promise;
          }
    }
    }
}

app.directive('customerValidator', ['$http', '$q', getCustomerValidationDirectiveFunc()]);
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<p><input type="text" ng-model="customer.customer_id" required customer-vlidator ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {default: 500, blur: 0}}"></input></p>
```

I want the input to check any input after a 500ms delay (debounce) and make an asynchronous call to my backend to set that field invalid if the customer already exists in the database... I'm not even SEEING an HTTP call being made on my network tab... so why is this not working???

Comment: In your html code example you have customer-vlidator, is this a typo or is that what you have in your current html?

Comment: that was a typo from when I was making the SO question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with in the end... I think the main problem was in passing the $q into the function in the right order. (**$q.defer is not a function**) as well as the if statement within the $http.get().then() callback.  It was **response.data.exist** and I changed it to **response.data === false** and am returning true or false from my validation endpoint.

JAVASCRIPT

```
app.directive('customerValidator', ['$q','$http', function($q, $http){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        var serverAddr = '/validate/customer/'

        ngModel.$asyncValidators.invalidCustomer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            // validation logic here
            var customer = viewValue || modelValue;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            // ask the server if this username exists
            $http.get(serverAddr+customer).then(
              function(response) {
                if (response.data === false) {
                  deferred.reject();
                } else {
                  deferred.resolve();
                }
              });

            // return the promise of the asynchronous validator
            return deferred.promise;
          }
    }
}}]);
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customer.customer_id" required customer-validator ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {default: 500, blur: 0}}"></input>
```